# windows 8 password reset

Tags: windows, windows-8, password-recovery, hiren

A friend of mine has accidentally lost her windows 8 password. I tried booting a live USB Hiren's & Windows windows unlocker enterprise (windows xp based live disks). The problem is that the normal mode is UEFI based (in BIOS) and it does not allow to boot Legacy OS (like xp). But when I enable "legacy mode", it disables the UEFI mode so Rescue CD's dont show the internal hard disk of laptop.

Any help ?

Comment: Are we talking about a local account or a microsoft login?

Comment: local account, not microsoft account

Comment: This was a Kickstarter project and has proven to be very handy in the week since I got the software. It can reset the password of any user on almost any version of Windows. It can also add new users or clone existing users.[PasswordResetKey](http://www.passwordresetkey.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could try, is boot into a Ubuntu Live OS and:

1. Rename C:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe to C:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe.bak
2. Rename C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe to C:\windows\system32\Utilman.exe
3. Load back into windows, and click the 'Ease of access' button on the logon screen, and command promt should now open.
4. Type: net user ###### * (replace hashes with the username)
5. Give them a new password

Comment: thats quite clever and nice trick ! ;)

Comment: Just remember to rename the programs back to Utilman.exe and cmd.exe :D

Comment: clever trick indeed! but before you should take ownership of the these `.exe` files in `system32` directory as by default it is `trustedinstaller` and then set permissions to `full control` in order to be able to rename them

Comment: Nah if you boot into Linux, it ignores all windows permissions. You could delete the entire System32 folder if you like Lol

Comment: This answer works much more reliably than the popular `chntpw` alternative, since it uses Windows tools for resetting password. `chntpw`, e.g., doesn't work with non-latin user names, and has been reported to sometimes not actually reset password despite apparent success.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the password reset using the Windows 8 installation media.

Here is an article explaining all the required steps to do so :

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/reset-password-windows-8.htm

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) quite successfully to reset Windows 8 local user password, bring local users into an administrator group, etc.

Just burn the ISO to a CD, enable Legacy Boot in BIOS, boot up the that CD and then go to "Windows Password Resetting" option.